# New BT mouse interferes with Apple keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

My kid smashed my Logitech M705, so I replaced it with a M720 that has BT as well as its own dongle. I used the BT to connect it. Suddenly my Apple BT keyboard is no longer working so well. Periodically it "goes nuts", almost always after pressing Command-Z for undo... it just keeps on undoing. It seems fine when you're just typing away, but do anything with command keys or such, and blamo.

Is this something I should expect, or not?

Comment: Is this a separate issue from your [other BT question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/270966/88313) or does that answer also fix this one?

Comment: It does not, I'm still having the same problems. Periodically.

Comment: Are you using the latest software from Logitech?  I know there were several questions here recently regarding Sierra and Logitech drivers that were solved with the last update.