# Why is this item bold in the Bluetooth menu?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

Can anyone tell me what the bold text means in this image of my Bluetooth menu?

[image: Bluetooth menu]

It seems that the mouse might be interfering with my keyboard, and I'm wondering if this is trying to say that?

Comment: Your Bluetooth menulet tries to indicate that (a) M720 Triathlon (mouse) is paired and connected.

Comment: Wow. They could have made that a lot more obvious!

Comment: The other two are paired but not connected (e.g. after removing the batteries)

Answer (score -1):

It means that particular device is active (in this case it's your Logitech mouse).